# How to reuse widget styles properly in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Coming from frontend webframeworks like angular, react and vue I am struggling to find the best way to write reusable widget styles. Let me demonstrate the problem with an example.

Lets say we have this Widget:

```
Container(
  width: 25,
  height: 10,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.black,
      width: 8.0,
      ),
    ),
  child: /* some custom widget */,
);
```

Now lets say I want to make the `Container` properties like `width`, `height` etc. changable by parameters. If a certain parameter for a property is not passed it should use its default value, like this:

```
class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final BoxDecoration decoration;

  const CustomWidget ({
    Key key,
    this.width = 25,
    this.height = 10,
    this.decoration = /* default decoration */
    /* possibly even more properties */
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      decoration: decoration,
      child: /* some custom widget */
  }
}
```

Obviously, there could be more properties which would lead to more and more boilerplate. Also what do you do, if the container does not have a decoration by default? Should you pass a custom Container always? Also consider that the Container could be nested further down the widget tree.

There must be a good solution, I just can't think of one, probably because my thoughts are biased because of my experience with frontend development. In web project you simply pass the component/widget custom css-classes to overwrite the styles (e.g. a parameter `containerClasses`). How do you do it properly in flutter?

**EDIT:** In essence my question is: Is there an equivalent to a css-class in flutter? Or: Whats the best way to make a custom widget's style totally customizable by parameters. I feel like i have to write every single property by hand.

In react you have an interface for all html elements  (e.g. `div`, `input` etc.) and their props (e.g. for an `input`-element you have an interface with `value`, `class`, `type` etc.), which you can use to define what parameters one can pass to customize the component/widget.

Comment: I fail to see what you do not understand if you're coming from Vue/React. Reusing style in Flutter is like scoped styled in Vue or the package styled-component in React.

Comment: I don't see how scoped style enhances reusability of styles. Also i editet my post, to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter style behaves similarly to Vue scoped styled / React "styled-component" or React native in general:

There's no "global style" in these scenarios. Instead, you use composition to obtain the desired result.

In a sense, you have one StatelessWidget for each "CSS class", instead of one big StatelessWidget with many parameters.

For example, say we want to split a "red background + border radius" into reusable styles, then we'd typically have two widgets:

- RedBackground
- MyBorder

where you would then be able to use them independently:

```dart
RedBackground(
  child: Text('hello world'),
)
```

or together:

```dart
RedBackground(
  child: MyBorder(
    child: Text('hello world'),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thats what I thought of too. The downside of  this approach is, that it leads to a lot of nesting, which is one of the few things i don't like about flutter. How ever, thats probably just the flutter way of doing things. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Well, you can make yet another stateless widget that combines multiple of these reusable widgets to reduce the nesting. That's what `Container` does.

Comment: I feel like I had this all in mind but thought it was the wrong way, thanks for clarifying. I should break out of my css-like thinking.